# IIS (express) wrong response mimetype when HTTP 401 (NTLM)

Tags: http, authentication, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, iis-express

In the scope of a web project in ASP MVC 5 hosted with IIS (express locally on widows 7),
my IIS Express is sending **HTTP 401** results only for some javascript files and css files.

Strangely enough, in such cases, while the response is correctly sent, the content-type is always `text/html; charset=utf-8` for both css or javascript files. For the rest of javascript / css files, when the server reply **HTTP 200**, the content-type is correctly set to either `application/javascript` or `text/css`.

When **HTTP 401** is sent, **WWW-Authenticate** is set to `NegotiateNTLM`.

I first thought it was the typescript-compiled js files that were not properly served, but some of other typescript-compiled files are correctly served.

**Across multiples refreshes, the set of the files concerned by the issue is not the same.**

Any idea ? This is preventing some of my SystemJS queries to work properly.

Comment: Check which sub status you hit, https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7.0,-iis-7.5,-and-iis-8.0